# I added a new chrome extension but the icon not appearing on right of address bar.

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, icons

Im just a user and I added a new extension, Peerio, to chrome and it installed but no icon to the right of address bas as supposed to be.

I checked the settings ->extensions and i see its installed, but can't us it.

Actually out of about 8 extensions i have installed only 3 are showing to the right of the address bar. Address bar seems very long, like 90 of the screen width and the 3 icons to the right.

Can someone tell me the trick to getting the address bar to shrink and reveal more icons?

I have windows Vista BTW.

thanks

Comment: There's only an icon if it has a browser action.

Comment: Voting to migrate to [su]

Comment: as for showing missing extension icons see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbAZXtaRi5o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peerio is an *app*, not an extension.

Therefore, it cannot even *have* a button there.

You can access it though `chrome://apps` or the "Apps" launcher on the New Tab page.

Comment: thanks, these are 2 things I didn't know about, the Apps launcher and the fact that it was not an extension. Believe it or not this was not made clear, but now I know thanks.

Comment: There is a quick way to tell.. In the Web Store, extensions' icons are embedded into a "jigsaw puzzle piece" when viewing their details.